# Can two Windows Phone 7.1 apps communicate? through socket maybe?

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, tcp, endpoint

Is it possible for two Windows Phone 7.1 apps to communicate with each other without an external server?

- WP7 apps are isolated
- WP7 apps don't support scheme uri
- WP7 apps don't support Bluetooth
- WP7 apps don't have native code or PInvoke support

So I thought I could open a socket so two WP7 apps could exchange through it:

```
var s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
var a = new SocketAsyncEventArgs
{
    RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 65535),
};
s.ConnectAsync(a);
```

But I don't know which `DnsEndPoint` would work? Is this approach technically possible? Or any other approach?

[in my example, I got a `SocketError.HostNotFound` on `Completed`]

Comment: For the socket approach to work, both apps would need to be running at the same time. However, only the foreground app is running, the others are suspended.

Comment: @KooKiz Oh right. Is that true for a BackgroundIntensiveTask?